# Threshoding image between certain range

Tags: c++, opencv, threshold

How  to Threshold image  between certain range?
i have done  this but it doesn't work.

```
for (int i=0;i<s.size().height;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<s.size().width;j++)
    {
        int k=int (s.at<uchar>(j,i));
        if (k>6 &&  k<10)
            k=255;
        else k=0;
            s.at<uchar>(j,i)=k;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What should it do and what happens instead? And which programming language is this?

Comment: Can't see any thing wrong with this code.

Comment: I am using visual studio(c++) opencv . i want to threshold intensities between 6 and 10.

Answer (score 1):

You get an uchar value, and convert it to integer. Try this :

```
    uchar k= s.at<uchar>(j,i);
    if (k>6 &&  k<10) {
        k=255;
     }else {
        k=0;
     }
     s.at<uchar>(j,i)=k;
```

I think it may work.